# android intercept recent apps button

Tags: android

I have an application meant for children and I do not want them to be able to click the "Recent Apps" button (the one that looks like two rectangles on top of each other). I am taking care of capturing the back button and the home button and I have searched and read a lot about about trying to capture the Recent Apps button, but most say you cannot or the way they do it is very questionable.

The App "Kids Place" pops up a view that says "Action Not Allowed" and redirects you to its home screen if you press the Recent Apps button, this works even if you are in a different app, so how are they doing this?

Comment: Yes, I have a home screen and I take care of that with an intent-filter. My question is with regard to the "Recent Apps" button.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but if all else fails you can try decompiling that app and see how they do it

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574239/how-to-disable-the-recent-tasks-apps-button-in-android?rq=1

Comment: do you want to hide your app from recent apps.?

Answer (score 22):

The current best solution I found is the following:

```
   @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (!hasFocus) {
        windowCloseHandler.postDelayed(windowCloserRunnable, 0);
    }
}

private void toggleRecents() {
    Intent closeRecents = new Intent("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
    closeRecents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    ComponentName recents = new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity");
    closeRecents.setComponent(recents);
    this.startActivity(closeRecents);
}

private Handler windowCloseHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable windowCloserRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;

        if (cn != null && cn.getClassName().equals("com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity")) {
            toggleRecents();
        }
    }
}
```

This requires that you use  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />`

When using this approach when the user presses the recent apps button it will cause your activity will go through the activity lifecycle as follows: onPause -> onWindowFocusChanged -> onResume.

To the user the behavior appears that pressing the recent apps button has no response. NOTE: that I have found that if you press the recent apps button quickly it will display that view for brief time.

Comment: Tricky, but does what it promises :) nice job!

Comment: "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity" is only for Android 4.2 - 4.4. See my reply for ClassNames for other Android versions.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found is to do this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

            Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

        if(!hasFocus) {
            Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
}// all credit goes here: http://www.juliencavandoli.com/how-to-disable-recent-apps-dialog-on-long-press-home-button/
```

This is not my own code, but this just hides the recent apps list from showing.

Comment: I tried this out and it does not work for me, SDK>=14 on Nexus 7.

Comment: For future reference: I believe this only works on Samsung devices.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 4.4.4 (API 19) Samsung SM-G357FZ (Ace 4).

Comment: this code will be triggered every time your app gains focus.

Answer (score 2):

In the accepted answer you're using ClassName only for Android 4.2 - 4.4. It won't work on 5.0 and higher, or Android 4.1.

Here is the list of ClassNames for main Android versions:

- Android 4.1: "com.android.internal.policy.impl.RecentApplicationsDialog"
- Android 4.2 - 4.4: "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity"
- Android 5.0 - 7.1: "com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity" ("s" letter was added)

The best solution for you will be to utilize Accessibility Service. 
Override `onAccessibilityEvent()` method, filter out ClassNames listed above and do something when you detect this event. For example simulate pressing the 'Home' button. You can do this by making a global action in Accessibility Service.

Answer (score 0):

thanks **esse** for solution for higher SDK! I missed it.

But in my case I need to duplicate call (or effect is unstable)

```
        if (SDK>15){
            windowCloseHandler.postDelayed(windowCloserRunnable, 10);
            windowCloseHandler.postDelayed(windowCloserRunnable, 300);
        }
```

Comment: I had to revisit this and encountered the unstable issue, thanks for your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in disabling all system buttons, may be the option would be to kill system bar completely, see [Easy way to hide system bar on Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445157/easy-way-to-hide-system-bar-on-android-ics#answer-19373504)