# Disable the buttons of an Android Device when an app is running

Tags: android

I'm developing an application and I need to **disable the virtual buttons** when the application started to run since there are buttons from the application.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1st_main);
    
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private final List hijackKeys = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME));

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (hijackKeys.contains(event.getKeyCode())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can hide the Navigation bar(not disable, just hide) from 4.0, refer to [developer.android.com/navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Comment: You can disable Back Button and Menu Button by Overriding but you can't  disable Home Button....

Comment: Hi @hypd09, thanks for the response! However, the code that you referred doesn't working.

Comment: @BlackTiger, how can I override that?

Comment: wait a min i will provide answer

Comment: You can't disable Home button even the power button.

Comment: How can I disable the Recent Task/Apps Button?

Comment: @TwistedDroid: heyy please check my answer i hope help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best solution for this.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

            Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

        if(!hasFocus) {
            Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

            Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
            sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        }
    }
} // all credit goes here: http://www.juliencavandoli.com/how-to-disable-recent-apps-dialog-on-long-press-home-button/
```

Answer (score 2):

Override Back Button with below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onBackPressed();  // nothing to do here
}
```

And now for Menu Button try like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);   // comment this line to disable menu button
    return true;
}
```

And best approach to disable menu button just remove onCreateOptionsMenu method from your activity class...

Comment: Do you know how can I disable the recent tasks/apps button? The one beside the Home Button...

Comment: Sorry not having completely idea about it... i will tel you if i found anything related it...

Comment: @TwistedDroid: Please try out this answer it may helps you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769367/android-intercept-recent-apps-button/17774643#17774643`

Comment: I found the right code in one of the answers from the link you've provided. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest.xml for your main activity:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

[source found from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button).

Try this way

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    //only desable home button
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```