# how to disable the recent apps button in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In my app i want to disable the recent apps button.

(i.e)When user press that button it doesn't show the recent running apps and reside on the same activity page.

I did that by following code. But it doesn't work in Android L.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (!hasFocus) {
            windowCloseHandler.postDelayed(windowCloserRunnable, 250);

        }
    }

    private void toggleRecents() {
        Intent closeRecents = new Intent("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
        closeRecents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
        ComponentName recents = new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity");
        closeRecents.setComponent(recents);
        this.startActivity(closeRecents);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Complete the test and go back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Handler windowCloseHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable windowCloserRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;



            if (cn != null && cn.getClassName().equals("com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity")) {
                toggleRecents();
            }
        }
    };
```

Please help to solve this issue in Android Lollipop.

Comment: Hie.AFAIK you cant disable the recent app button. but I have a solution with  that your Activity will  not seen in recent Apps. use this :  android:excludeFromRecents="true"  in all the Activities in your Menifest file. May be it will help you.

Comment: or as per your requirement : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574239/how-to-disable-the-recent-tasks-apps-button-in-android

Comment: @MDroid thanks for your response. But if i do like that your suggestion it didn't show my app in recent apps. Even though user presses the recent apps button my app control don't exit  and shows the current activity page.

Comment: I get your issue. When user is in App and press recent app button--> and again start the app it will show the current Activity . Am i right ?

Comment: @MDroid I already tried this( stackoverflow.com/questions/14574239/ ) link. From that only i got the code in my question.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" /> Have you add this permission in menifest ?

Comment: yes u are right. it will show the window which is currently accessed by user. At the same time the activity doesn't reload that is main concept.

Comment: AFAIK you cant override the Recent app button as we generally do with back button in Android!

Comment: I added that permission in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below. but the problem is though, after someone click on recent app button, the action call after a second and if he/she quickly clear the app from the list, your app is lost.

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus) {
        // Close every kind of system dialog
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

Cheers!